# I deploy create-react-app in vercel and vercel block http requests but API not have https version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, vercel

when I take the data of the films [https://www.omdbapi.com/‘](https://www.omdbapi.com/%E2%80%98) After hosting on Versel, I have an error:: useMovies.js:21 Mixed Content: The page at ‘https://usepopcorn-mu.vercel.app/‘ was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ‘http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=3cc2a1e3&s=tes’. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. I sort of understand what is going on but I don't know how I'm supposed to go about fixing it, the API doesn't have a https version, are there other ways of fixing this?

I looked almost everywhere but to no avail, since there was no answer to be found. other people also asked in the repository but there was no answer there either. everything works fine on local host.